# Javascript: get contour of polygon / remove inside lines

Tags: javascript, math, border, polygon, contour

I've a polygon and I want to get the contour of it, it looks like this:

```
<polygon fill="transparent" points=" -60.48565220947266,46.13742103271485, 56.557547790527344,46.13742103271485, 56.557547790527344,-5.06897780456543, -60.48565220947266,-5.06897780456543, 37.050350115966786,-9.94577780456543, -85.80719033203123,-9.94577780456543, -85.80719033203123,46.13742103271485, 56.34799779052733,46.13742103271485, 56.34799779052733,19.315022195434572, 37.050350115966786,19.315022195434572, -74.9509506591797,-5.06897780456543, -74.9509506591797,46.13742103271485, 56.347997790527344,46.13742103271485, 56.347997790527344,19.315022195434572, 37.0503501159668,19.315022195434572, 37.0503501159668,-9.94577780456543, -30.333590332031253,-9.94577780456543, -30.333590332031253,-5.06897780456543, 37.0503501159668,-5.06897780456543" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 1px;" stroke-dasharray="5, 5" id="#contour"></polygon>
```

```html
<svg>
<g transform="translate(100,100)">
<polygon fill="transparent" points=" -60.48565220947266,46.13742103271485, 56.557547790527344,46.13742103271485, 56.557547790527344,-5.06897780456543, -60.48565220947266,-5.06897780456543, 37.050350115966786,-9.94577780456543, -85.80719033203123,-9.94577780456543, -85.80719033203123,46.13742103271485, 56.34799779052733,46.13742103271485, 56.34799779052733,19.315022195434572, 37.050350115966786,19.315022195434572, -74.9509506591797,-5.06897780456543, -74.9509506591797,46.13742103271485, 56.347997790527344,46.13742103271485, 56.347997790527344,19.315022195434572, 37.0503501159668,19.315022195434572, 37.0503501159668,-9.94577780456543, -30.333590332031253,-9.94577780456543, -30.333590332031253,-5.06897780456543, 37.0503501159668,-5.06897780456543" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 1px;" stroke-dasharray="5, 5" id="#contour"></polygon>
</g>
</svg>
```

[image]

I want to remove everything that is inside of the polygon and keep only the border, my math skills are low and I'm having trouble making it to work.
How can I achive this?

Comment: → https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms